# UniGui TuniDbLookupComboBox autosearch based on user input

Tags: delphi

I started checking out UniGui WebFramework for Delphi and I wonder if TuniDbLookupComboBox allows user to perform autosearch on the lookup dataset as he writes. As far as I can see user is not allowed to write in a TuniDbLookupComboBox but only choose from the dropdown that contains lookup dataset results.

Thank you very much
Nick

Comment: \have you asked on the UniGui support forms http://forums.unigui.com/?

Answer (score 0):

There are several demos related to TUniDBLookupComboBox. They demonstrate how to search based on partial user input.